# php help for a flash card program

Tags: php, database, web-applications

I am working on a small web app that queries a database.  I wanted the script to only cycle through the each flash card once and show an "end of stack" alert at the end, but as the script is written it will scroll through the set indefinitely.  I was wondering if anyone could help me out with this?  The database has fields for card_id (1,2,3...[each entry has a unique number]), card_type (either 0 [term based],1 [question based]), class (subject), sub_class (division of that subject), side_1 (data), side_2 (data).  Here's the code I have so far:

```
   <?php

//Sample Database Connection Syntax for PHP and MySQL.
    //Connect To Database
    $hostname="";
    $username="";
    $password="";
    $dbname="";
    $usertable="flash_cards";
    $question = "side_1";
    $answer = "side_2";
    $connection = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password);
    mysql_select_db($dbname, $connection);
    $count=0;

    // this section generates the flashcards
    $query = "SELECT * FROM $usertable ";
    if(empty($_GET)) {

    }
    else {
        $query .= " WHERE ";

        if($_GET["sub_class"] != null){
            $query .= "sub_class = '".$_GET["sub_class"]."'";
            if($_GET["card_type"] != null){
                $query .= " AND card_type = ".$_GET["card_type"];
            }
        }
        else if($_GET["card_type"] != null){
            $query .= " card_type = ".$_GET["card_type"];
        }
    }

    $query .= " ORDER BY RAND() ";

    //echo $query;

    $result = mysql_query($query);
    if($result){
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
            if($count == 0){
                $class = $row["class"];
                $sub_class = $row["sub_class"];
                echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"".$count."\" value=\"".$class." - ".$sub_class."\"/>";
                $count += 1;
                echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"".$count."\" value=\""."\"/>";
                $count += 1;
            }

            $name = $row["$question"];
            $name2 = $row["$answer"];
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"".$count."\" value=\"".$name."\"/>";
            $count += 1;
            echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"".$count."\" value=\"".$name2."\"/>";
            $count += 1;
        }
        echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"count\" value=\"".$count."\"/>";

}


?>
```

Comment: FYI, you are **wide open** to SQL injection and **you will be hacked** if you haven't been already.  Learn to do prepared queries with PDO to avoid this problem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. I'm connecting and making the query as per GoDaddy's connection example. If you don't mind, could you show me a better way this can be done, as to avoid this in the future?

Comment: Sure, I recommend this tutorial:  http://www.phpro.org/tutorials/Introduction-to-PHP-PDO.html  It covers the relevant parts of PDO for your purposes.  I would take GoDaddy's tutorials with a large grain of salt.

Answer (score 0):

Save a unique id for each card shown for each user in either an array in a session, in a cookie, or in a database. When you query for cards use `WHERE unique_id NOT IN($ids)`

Comment: i do have an id or each entry of the database, but i need a random output for each instance and no duplications.  i think an array would work if i were queried by the card_id, but i don't know how this would code.  Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Other posters have mentioned this, but it bears reiterating: use PDO to prepare your sql statement to avoid injection attacks and hacking.

To the point of your question; what you probably want to do is get your result and *then* randomize, as it will be more efficient:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
$shuffled_deck = array();
if($result) {
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $shuffled_deck[] = $row;
    }

    shuffle($shuffled_deck);

    foreach ($shuffled_deck as $row) {
        //output your stuff here
    }
    echo "<input type=\"hidden\" id=\"count\" value=\"".$count."\"/>";
}
```

Comment: I see the value in doing it this way, and thank you for the suggestion.  i have since changed the code as per your suggestion, but I still have the problem of an infinite loop of output (with reiteration of past cards during use). Any suggestions for that?

Comment: I think maybe I'm not quite understanding you then. Your query should produce the total set of cards in your database, filtered by subclass and type if those filters are set. You then go on to display all of them. On what basis do you want to limit the cards you're displaying? Is the problem just that the same set of cards will keep coming up each time you load the page?

Comment: The filter is working great, but I want to limit the output to the total number of cards in that sub_class. So basically I want to only show each card once. As it's set up now it just loops through a random assortment of the sub class indefinitely. So, preferentially I want to start the stack showing the class and sub_class they are about to see, followed by the stack only showing a random assortment of the cards (each card only once), and finishing with a message like "end of the set". HoPefully this clarifies. Thanks.

Comment: Is one card shown per page, or are you showing the whole set? In short I think you want your query to only return the cards you want to show... it's just a question of how you want to define that. 'class' and 'subclass' don't make much sense to me, I admit. Perhaps provide a concrete example?

Comment: The script pulls up all of the entries for a class (biology, gen-chem or o-chem) and one sub class (microbiology, human phys, genetics), and displays one card at a time (first the question=> touch event=>answer=>touchevent=>next question.. and so on. I also have a card_type field in the database (0= term based and 1=question based).  So a query would be www. mywebsite.com/myscript.php?class=biology&sub_class=microbiology&card_type=0. Returns biology terms from microbiology that are terms and not questions (like:  [side_1] cell wall; touchevent; [side_2] lipid bilayer). Does this help?

Comment: Then what you probably want is to do the initial pull on page-load and save out the sequence of cards to a session variable, along with a counter, so subsequent page loads can check to see if that is there, and if it is, use the next card in the sequence. You don't want to run the db query with each page load, just manipulate the first set of results.